# Get value of Nested JSON objects according to certain value (C#)

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was making a test Xamarin Android application which requires me to parse JSON data. Parsing simple JSON data was easy enough, but this JSON data seems a little too complicated to understand.

What I want to do :

Based on the `Latitude` and `Longitude`, I want to extract that particular JSON object.

Here's the data : https://pastebin.com/raw/7QDh2uZH

What I have so far :

```
private async Task JsonFetcher()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://pastebin.com");

        var result = await client.GetAsync("/raw/7QDh2uZH");
        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        try
        {
            dynamic obj2 = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(resultContent);
        }
        catch (Exception GettingError)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

What I have right now just desirializes the JSON data and I can get value of one record by accessing it by something like : `obj2.meta` (will give out the value of meta).

What can I do to extract the particular record? Any idea or suggestions would be great.

Comment: use org2.data[0] to access the first element of the data array, etc...  or deserialize the json into a structured c# class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to optimize for your particular purpose, but if you are just trying to find the node with latitude and longitude you are looking for, this will do the trick.

```
for( int x = 0; x < obj2.data.Count; x++)
{
   var y = obj2.data[x].Location.Latitude;
   var z = obj2.data[x].Location.Longitude;
   if (y.Value == desiredLat && z.Value == desiredLong)
   {
       return obj2.data[x];
   }
}
```

Comment: You could also create a class based on the JSON structure and deserialize the JSON to the class.  Then you could treat it like any other c# object.  This would actually be the preferable approach.  something like this: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomJSONClass>(jsonString);

Comment: Ah, this was rather easy once you know how to iterate over the JSON nodes. Thank you mate, this is a life saver and thanks for the suggestion :)